# PrEndere but tenEre

Tags: verbs, pronunciation

Could anyone refer me to a rule explaining why verbs ending with -ere have different stressed syllables? What I have understood so far is that I should look them up in the dictionary.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Comment: More than three years later, my best suggestion is to still look them up in the dictionary. 

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Conventionally, people say that Italian verbs fall into three categories, or conjugations: those ending in *-are*, in *-ere* and in *-ire*. Those in *-ere*, however, correspond to two different conjugations in Latin (where there were four conjugations for verbs):

- those in *-ēre*, where “ē” is a long, and stressed, vowel (2nd Latin conjugation);
- and those in *-ĕre*, where “ĕ” is short and unstressed, and the stress fell on the previous syllable (3rd Latin conjugation).

So, about your examples, *tenere* derives from *tenēre* (first person *teneo*, which is how you'll find it in a Latin vocabulary); and the analogous holds for verbs such as *dovere*, *godere*, *persuadere*, *vedere*, the derivates of *tenere* (such as *trattenere*, *mantenere*, *contenere* and so on) etc.

On the other hand, *prendere* derives from *prehendĕre* (*prehendo*), and an analogous stress is found in other verbs from Latin third conjugation, such as *giungere*, *leggere*, *tendere*, *vincere* and many more.

I am afraid this is not of much help unless one knows well one's Latin, and moreover there are exceptions: verbs that have modified their stress with respect to their Latin ancestor, such as Italian *rìdere*, from Latin *ridēre*, *mòrdere* from *mordēre* and so on.